# Auto reply in Gmail, Why does an error come out when a new letter arrives?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

Good afternoon, I found this script in the open and optimized it for my tasks, but for some reason it does not respond to incoming letters. There is a trigger for 1 minute, but when an incoming letter arrives I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null in Line 29`
I cannot understand what the problem is, what am I doing wrong?
I will be glad for any help

```
function autoReply() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var answer = ss.getRange("A2").getValue();
  var fileattach = ss.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var mimetype = ss.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var interval = 1;
  var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var daysOff = [1,2,3,4,5,6,0];
  if (daysOff.indexOf(day) > -1){
    var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
    var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      if (threads[i].isUnread()){
         var sender=threads[i].getMessages()[0].getFrom();
        if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys().length==0){
           PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('from', '');
         }
        var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('fromArray');
        var attach = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileattach).next();
        if(scriptProperties.indexOf(sender)==-1){
          threads[i].reply(answer,{
          attachments:[attach.getAs(mimetype)]                
          });
          threads[i].markRead();
          scriptProperties=scriptProperties+sender; 
          PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('from',  scriptProperties);
          }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the `scriptProperties` variable is not null? If you do `console.log(scriptProperties)` what are you receiving?

Comment: [20-11-12 17:00:04:516 YEKT] TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null at autoReply(Code:21:29)

Comment: And what is the value of the `scriptProperties` variable?

Comment: Sorry, my English is very bad, I don't understand your question

Comment: The error you are getting is because `scriptProperties` might be null. What are you receiving if you add `console.log(scriptProperties)` in line 28 of your script?

Comment: Same mistake((  TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null at autoReply(Code:21:29)

Comment: First, fix your naming - it is a bad idea to call a single entity `scriptProperties`. Believe me, it will bite you some day. Also, avoid calls to `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()` in a loop, access it once and save into a variable. The reason for your error is likely to be `.getProperty('fromArray')` - why would you expect it to not be null if you save `.setProperty('from', '')`?

Comment: @Oleg Valter
Thank you, mistake really was in `.getProperty('fromArray')` change on `.getProperty('from')`

Comment: NP, happens. I would really advise not to call script properties in a loop - you will exhaust the quota pretty quickly depending on the number of calls.

Comment: Please tell me, how I can change the code with your adjustment                                                            
 > >Also, avoid calls to `PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()` in a loop, access it once and save into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of null in Line 29` error message that you are receiving is due to the fact that you are trying to call the `indexOf` method of a `null` object.

More specifically, your error is coming from this line here

```
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('fromArray');
```

And when you are calling `scriptProperties.indexOf` since `scriptProperties` is `null` in this situation.